GitHub: Как получить собранный релиз из Latest в программе на C#?
Собственно сабж: есть графическая оболочка, управляющая консольным приложением. Само консольное приложение регулярно обновляется. Каждый раз перепаковывать и выкладывать обновленную версию надоело. Есть ли вариант получения готового релиза из Latest с GitHub, учитывая что архивы в зависимости от версии имеют различные имена и разные теги?

Не понял, вам скачать надо или что? Если да, то используйте API, а именно https://api.github.com/repos/<имя>/<репозиторий>/releases/latest, далее забираете zipball_url, которая и будет ссылкой на прямое скачивание данного релиза в ZIP формате.

Так, вот это уже интереснее. С API гитхаба не приходилось сталкиваться. Да, мне именно надо скачать собранный релиз, а не его исходники. И именно в ZIP. В нужном репозитории он всегда и точно есть. Можно простой пример как мне забрать zipball_url, к примеру отсюда: https://github.com/ShadelessFox/decima/releases/latest

Не ленитесь, там простейший JSON с которым справиться любой новичок. Только если вам надо именно релиз, то тогда assets берите, находите нужный и в нем уже забирайте browser_download_url.

Отлично. Именно то, что нужно и даже понятно =)) Благодарю.

Все оказалось до безобразия просто и давно расписано.
Получение последнего релиза из GitHub разными методами (cURL, JS, GitHub CLI)
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-latest-release
cURL:
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/releases/latest

Код на C# будет выглядеть так:
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.github+json"));//ПРИНЯТЬ заголовок
string request = "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/releases/latest";
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ".NET Foundation Repository Reporter"); // НЕОБХОДИМО, ИНАЧЕ ОШИБКА 403
var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(request);
var jArray = await response;
var url = JObject.Parse(jArray).SelectToken("assets[0].browser_download_url").ToString();// ПАРСИМ URL


Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
